# ionic input v-model is not working in my code

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework

it's my first time trying Ionic + Vue App and in `ionic-input` the v-model is not working ... any help please?

```js
    data() {
      return {

        model: {
          email: '',
          password: '',
        
        }
```

```html
   <ion-input alternative
                              class="mb-3"
                              name="password"
                              :rules="{required: true, min: 6}"
                              prepend-icon="ni ni-lock-circle-open"
                              type="password"
                              v-model="model.password">
                  </ion-input>
```

Comment: How do you know it not working?   Your code appears to be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have the same issue. I've fixed it with :value and @ionInput.

```
<ion-input alternative
                          class="mb-3"
                          name="password"
                          :rules="{required: true, min: 6}"
                          prepend-icon="ni ni-lock-circle-open"
                          type="password"
                          :value="model.password"
                          @ionInput="model.password = $event.target.value;">
              </ion-input>
```

Found it here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/15532#issuecomment-420031134

Comment: this is incorrect... the issue you referenced has been closed for years and addressed in ionic

Comment: I know, but that fix just work

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I was missing the IonInput import:

```
import {
  IonInput,
} from '@ionic/vue';
```

Comment: This answer cannot be emphasised enough. Especially when running the full Production build in release mode it appears to work but strange behavior happens depending on the component it may even still work when run in debug non-production builds which makes the production bug reports very difficult to debug.