# ionic Vue 3 - Compositon API - V-model does not update the values

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am having some problems with using v-model in my ionic application. It does not seems to update the data while using two way binding. See my code:

```html
<template>
    <form class="ion-padding" @submit.prevent="submitForm">
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label position="flaoting">Title</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text" v-model="enteredTitle" />
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label position="flaoting">Image URL</ion-label>
          <ion-input type="url" required v-model="enteredImageUrl" />
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label position="flaoting">Description</ion-label>
          <ion-textarea rows="5" v-model="enteredDescription"></ion-textarea>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
      <ion-button type="submit" expand="full">Save</ion-button>
    </form>
  </template>
  
  <script lang="ts">
  import { reactive, toRefs } from 'vue';
  export default {
      setup() {
          const enteredMemoryData = reactive({ 
            enteredTitle: '',
            enteredImageUrl: '',
            enteredDescription: '',
          });
  
          // METHOD
          function submitForm(){
              console.log('Form is getting submitted');
              const memoryData = {
                title: enteredMemoryData.enteredTitle,
                imageUrl: enteredMemoryData.enteredImageUrl,
                description: enteredMemoryData.enteredDescription,
              }
              console.log('Following data will be submitted', memoryData);
          }
          return {
              ...toRefs(enteredMemoryData),
              submitForm
          }
      },
  }
  </script>
```

Whenever I press the button I get the following console outputs:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you're using Ionic 5 and Vue 3, you need to `import { IonInput } from '@vue/ionic'` and `v-model` should work. [Similar issue](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/v-model-doesnt-work-in-ion-textarea/204950/8). If that doesn't work, you can also add reactivity yourself, as suggested in Nikola's answer, or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71588979/ionic-input-v-model-is-not-working-in-my-code), or this [github issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/15532#issuecomment-420031134).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ionic input v-model is not working in my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71588979/ionic-input-v-model-is-not-working-in-my-code)

Comment: @tao Yes and no. These are all examples of options API related questions. While I am using the composition API. I will try to find out what is going on. In the meantime the solution of Nikola is working for me hence this is not the way I want to have it solved. I still want to use the v-model. I will deep dive a bit more into this.

Comment: Options API and Composition API are different syntaxes. Anything written in one can be written in the other. Whether you can (or cannot) use `v-model` on Ionic components has no direct relation with the syntax used. If it works in one syntax, it works in the other and *vice-versa*. It works if `v-model` has been implemented on the Ionic components (which are Vue components). It's down to the version of Ionic + Vue you're using. According to the links above, there are versions in which using `v-model` is not possible, you'd have to use `:value` and `@change`.

Comment: @tao indeed. I am sorry I did some more research and your are right. I am now adding to every vue page all the components. Then it might be the case that it will work. If so then you really helped me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `:value` and `@input` instead `v-model`:

```js
const { IonicVue } = '@ionic/vue'
const { reactive, toRefs } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const enteredMemoryData = reactive({ 
      enteredTitle: '',
      enteredImageUrl: '',
      enteredDescription: '',
    });
    function submitForm(){
      console.log('Form is getting submitted');
      const memoryData = {
        title: enteredMemoryData.enteredTitle,
        imageUrl: enteredMemoryData.enteredImageUrl,
        description: enteredMemoryData.enteredDescription,
      }
      console.log('Following data will be submitted', enteredMemoryData);
    }
    return {
      ...toRefs(enteredMemoryData),
      submitForm
    }
  },
})
app.use(IonicVue)
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/css/ionic.bundle.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <form class="ion-padding" @submit.prevent="submitForm">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="flaoting">Title</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" :value="enteredTitle" @input="enteredTitle=$event.target.value" />
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="flaoting">Image URL</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="url" required :value="enteredImageUrl" @input="enteredImageUrl=$event.target.value"  />
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="flaoting">Description</ion-label>
        <ion-textarea rows="5" :value="enteredDescription" @input="enteredDescription=$event.target.value" ></ion-textarea>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <ion-button type="submit" expand="full">Save</ion-button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

v-model is just working as expected. I just forgot to include the imports:

```
components: {
  IonList,
  IonItem,
  IonLabel,
  IonInput,
  IonTextarea,
  IonButton,
},
```